# Como crear una variable autoincrementable en jmeter

Tags: rendimiento, jmeter

Necesito crear una variable en jmeter para enviar siempre un valor autoincrementable único en la petición, de momento estoy usando un contador. El problema es que me toma de nuevo el valor inicial del contador al momento de lanzar otra simulación con mas usuarios y la única solución es actualizarlo de manera manual.

Esta es la petición donde siempre tengo que enviarle un requestId
[image: Esta es la petición donde siempre tengo que enviarle un requestId diferente]

Aquí creo un contador y lo inicializo con 110001
[image: Contador]

El contador funciona correctamente pero al volver a lanzar la prueba con mas usuarios, me toca actualizar el contador de manera manual ya que el campo requestId no se puede repetir
[image: Aquí me tomo 110001 y 110002 en las primeras 2 peticiones pero al momento de realizar otra prueba me toma de nuevo 110001]

Comment: Hola Adrían, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y pongas tu código como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos, 
mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: Si la respuesta de un usuario, soluciona tu problema, puedes marcarla como "**aceptada**", si esta (o un comentario) no solucionó el problema, pero te ayudo a hacerlo, puedes darle un "**flechaParaArriba**", recuerda, del otro lado hay personas igual que tú, que dedican parte de su tiempo (gratuitamente) a ayudar a sus colegas, es una buena forma de agradecerles... y por supuesto, un "gracias" es la gloria.

Answer (score 0):

invoca la variable para el campo `requestId` como `${MiContador}`